# JFrame Menu get hidden

Tags: java, swing

When adding my canvas in JFrame Menu, why my menu always hide behind my canvas?

```
    canvas = new MyCanvas();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    contain.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your canvas into contentpane,

```
this.getContentPane().add(canvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```